# Windows 10 Desktop Icons in Tile View Mode

Tags: windows-10, desktop, icons, desktop-customization, desktop-icons

Not sure why this is happening, but all my Windows 10 icons are listing their file size. Each icon has a KB or Byte list next to them and the icon box is super duper wide. Folders are not like this, they don't display any indicator of their size, but their box is super wide like the one I show in the picture.

[image]

Windows 10 64 Bit Pro version.
I have Displayfusion and Stardock Fences installed, but I don't think they've caused this, but they do affect icons and backgrounds and etc.
Running an Nvidia GPU, Geforce Experience, etc.

I am running 3 monitors with the middle one being 4k and the other two being 1080p. This has caused some minor issues with icons and wallpapers in the past, but I have never enabled any option to have icons list their size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Desktop view is accidentally set to Tiles (or perhaps caused by "Bags" corruption).

Right-click Desktop, click View, and select one of the icon views > Small/Medium/Large.

Alternately, here are the keyboard combinations you can use:
(First, click an empty area on the desktop)

`Ctrl + Shift + 1` - Extra Large Icons

`Ctrl + Shift + 2` - Large Icons

`Ctrl + Shift + 3` - Medium Icons

`Ctrl + Shift + 4` - Small Icons

`Ctrl + Shift + 5` - List

`Ctrl + Shift + 6` - Details

`Ctrl + Shift + 7` - Tiles

`Ctrl + Shift + 8` - Content

Comment: What is "Bags" corruption?

Comment: [Bags](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813711) is the registry key that stores your folder preferences. It can become corrupt over time and if it does, then one needs to reset the folder views via Folder Options or in the [registry](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-folder-views-bags-windows/).